# Can I 'contrive a plan' ? Would it result in redundancy?

Tags: meaning, redundancy

For example: 'He contrived a plan to thwart his promotion'.
From what I could find , 'contrive' had the meaning 'to invent , devise'. So like we can say that 'He devised a plan'/'He invented a scheme' etc , it should be correct right? 
 I could not find any sentences that used 'contrive' this particular way tho. 
*ELI5*

Comment: Please see my comments at michael.hor257k below.

Answer (score 1):

*"Contrive"* means *to plan*, so seemingly *"contrive a plan"* would be a redundant repetition.

However, the *Oxford Advanced Learner's Dictionary* gives the following example sentence in its definition of ***[contrive](https://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/english/contrive)***:

> They contrived a plan to defraud the company.

This comes under the meaning of:

> to think of or make something, for example a plan or a machine, in a clever way

So I guess that means yes (in the right context).

---

See also [Ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=contrived%20a%20plan&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Ccontrived%20a%20plan%3B%2Cc0).

Comment: No hasty decisions. *Contrive* is **not** a synonym of *plan*.

Comment: In the same resource you cited, see def: **3 contrive something** to think of or make something, for example a plan or a machine, in a clever way *They contrived a plan to defraud the company.* -- Note the phrase "contrived a plan."

Comment: OTOH, the nGram for "contrived a plan" follows the same profile as for "contrived" -- so the decline is in the usage of the verb itself and not the phrase.

Comment: @Kris. So, would it be okay to state 'contrived' as well as 'contrived a plan' ? *Whenever contextually appropriate ofcourse!

Comment: @Specter Sure! Absolutely. I do it all the time.

Comment: @michael.hor257k. Thank you for sharing the sentence , I have lost my copy of the oxford dictionary. And I couldn't find any sentances that uses 'contrive' in the corresponding manner. P.S I tried upvoting but it'd seem that my points aren't adequate :P .

Comment: @Kris I have no idea what you want or why you keep pesting me. Please cease and desist.

Comment: @michael.hor257k No offense at all.